# Formatting text editor with Elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor with an OceanWP theme. I'm trying to customize a text editor that has many lines of text. I have 2 questions about how to tailor the content of the text editor:

1. Is it possible to prevent Elementor from adding space between paragraphs (in a similar way to how MS Word handles this matter)?
2. When I click on bold font, the text editor is actually using the expression `<strong>` rather than `<bold>` as I was expecting. The thing is that I would like to increase the contrast with the regular font but `<bolder>` and `<stronger>` do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'd add some custom CSS

1. You could add some custom CSS to override the margin on the paragraph elements within Elementor text block.  Here's some psuedocode:

```css
    .elementor-text-editor-block p {
      margin-bottom:0!important;
    }
```

2. Similarly, add something like

```css
strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Great, will you accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it?